# Will a Win7 RAID drop less than a fakeraid?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, raid

Up till recently I was using a 5 disk, 2TB, Raid-0 without any problems. However I added another drive bringing it up to 6 disks. Now the Raid drops and I have to reboot Windows to get it back. This doesn't happen with 5 drives. I'm using a FakeRaid from my AMD 870-G45 mother board.

It drops when I do heavy data work such as multicore solid 7zip or copying data to a just(almost)-as-fast destination. If I copy a big sparse file from the Raid, it just dies. If I limit the copy speed the Raid remains stable. So I was wondering if this could be fixed by swapping to a Win7 Software Raid. Also, should I swap to a Span and take the speed hit for stability?

Comment: You may not be aware that RAID level 0 actually increses your chances of data loss. For example with 2 hard drives in RAID level 0 if 1 drive fails 100% of the data is irrecoverable. For you if 1 of the 6 drives fail you loose 100% of your data. Make sure you're doing regular backups.

Comment: I have a complete backup. I wish Win7 could add disks to an existing Array. If it could I'd swap to a Raid 5 and canibilize the other 6 I use for the Backup. I'd also like to point out that if I spanned the disks and one fails, I'd still loose all the data.

Comment: Perhaps your raid controller doesn't support 6 drives. Also, what kind of PSU are you using?

Comment: It's a 950w monster. I'm just thinking that the fakeraid just isn't up to the task. Right now there are 10 hd's in the system, but their green drives. I've read that green drives don't like raid, but it was never an issue till drive 6 was added to the raid array. The other four are not in any sort of raid.

Comment: I went ahead and turned it into a Win7 Raid 0 and it's working perfectly. In fact it's working better than the fakeraid ever did.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and turned it into a Win7 Raid 0 and it's working perfectly. In fact it's working better than the fakeraid ever did. I benched it and it's moving faster with less lag. It handles sparse files with ease. In short, it's exactly what I wanted. Question - Answered!

Comment: You can accept your own answer, since more than 48 hours have passed since you asked your question.  Click on the check below the voting controls to accept your answer.